Machine epsilon and zero
I will use $\varepsilon$ to denote machine epsilon.
Usually, when doing comparisons of things like matrices, for example, one tends to say that the answer is "close enough" if the result is roughly machine epsilon or below. As an example, I may compute iterates $A_n$ that are supposed to tend to a matrix $A$, and then I will check $\Vert A_n - A \Vert$ to see if I have converged (and say that it has if the norm is $\leq \varepsilon$).
However, I can't reconcile this with the definition of machine epsilon. One way to define it is as a bound on the relative error in the representation of a floating point number, but the relative error does not exist for zero. The other common definition is that it is the smallest number $\varepsilon$ such that the representations of $1$ and $1+\varepsilon$ are different. Again, I can't really relate this back to "close enough to zero if below $\varepsilon$."
One also has that $x+y=x(1+y/x)$, so $y/x < \varepsilon/2$ implies that the representations of $x$ and $x+y$ are the same. I'm not really getting anything useful out of this either if $x=0$ or $y=0$.
The best statement I can make at the moment is something along the lines of "because of error propagation, etc., we usually stop if below $\varepsilon$" and similar "voodoo."
Isn't there some better reason grounded in theory?

In practice, we typically terminate an iteration when $|A_n-A| \leq \tau_r|A_0-A| + \tau_a$ instead of $|A_n-A| \leq\varepsilon$. $\tau_a$ can be taken to be smaller than $\varepsilon$ for the reason you state

Realistically, you are not comparing $A_n$ against the exact value of $A$, rather you have obtained an approximation $\hat{A}$ of $A$ using a different algorithm. Now you cannot hope to do better than $$\hat{A} = \text{fl}(A),$$ where $$\hat{a}_{ij} = \text{fl}(a_{ij})$$ is the floating point representation of $a_{ij}$. It $a_{ij}$ is in the representational range, then there exists $\delta_{ij}$ such that
$$\hat{a}_{ij} = a_{ij}(1 + \delta_{ij}), \quad |\delta_{ij}| \leq u$$ where $u$ is the unit roundoff. It follows that $$|A - \hat{A}| \leq u |A|$$ where the inequality should be understood in the componentwise sense. Since $$\|A\|_\infty = \||A|e\|_\infty,$$ where $e$ is the vector of ones, it is clear that we cannot hope to do better than $$\|A - \hat{A}\|_\infty \leq u \|A\|_\infty.$$ Realistically, we have
$$\|A - \hat{A}\|_\infty \leq \tau \|A\|_\infty$$
for some small value of $\tau < 1$, that is nevertheless substantially larger than $u$. What can be said about $A - A_n$? By the triangle inequality we have
$$ \|A - A_n\|_\infty \leq \|A - \hat{A} \|_\infty + \|\hat{A} - A_n\|_\infty \leq \tau \|A\|_\infty + \|\hat{A} - A_n\|_\infty$$
Now if $\tau$ is sufficiently small, then we can also tolerate a relative error of $2 \tau$. This can very nearly be achieved if we iterate until
$$ \|\hat{A} - A_n \| \leq \tau \|\hat{A}\|_\infty$$
In this case
$$ \|A - A_n\|_\infty \leq \tau ( \|A\|_\infty + \|\hat{A}\|_\infty) \approx 2 \tau \|A\|_\infty.$$
